# [Vue.2x]How to use <script> to get the data from Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use a `function` which in `script` but not in the `export default{}` get the data from `Vuex`(store) which had computed.

Example:
`<script>
getData function() {}
export default {} 
</script>`

Comment: why? sounds weird at first... maybe put the function in an external module and import it? then use it in your methods...

Comment: may i know what are you trying to do ?

Comment: in your store file,you can add a line: 
window.store = store = new Vuex.Store({...}),and then you can use window.store to get store instance.
but this is a wrong way, which will destroy the response characteristics of vuex.